# Convert this SQL query with calculations and table updates to stored proc

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone assist in converting this query into a stored procedure for MySQL.

The Query is as follows >

```
UPDATE
    `2015-06`
SET
    `Cost`=(
                CEIL(
                        `DurationMin`*65.00
                    )/100
            ),
    `Location`='New Caledonia - Mobile'
WHERE
    `Cost` IS NULL

    AND

    SUBSTR(
            `Dialed`,
            1,
            8
    ) = '01168779'
```

Briefly explained, this query is run multiple times with the following parameters that change (explained)

`2015-06` == This is the Month.
`65.00` == This is the Amount per minute charge. I divide by 100 as the DB has some weird float issues that crop up otherwise so the pennies are stored as whole numbers without decimal.
`New Caledonia - Mobile` == This is the location string.
`01168779` == The first (in this case `8`) digits to check for.

The SUBSTR, gets the first X number of digits from the Dialed field. The number (in this case `8`) needs to be a parameter as well.

Pseudo-code for the resulting stored procedure or function (i get confused between the two), is as follows (how i imagine it should be)

```
Foo(
     <varchar> TableName, # In the above example, the `2015-06` position
     <int> Amount, # In the above example, the `65.00` position
     <varchar> Location, # ... `New Caledonia - Mobile` position
     <int> DigitLength, # The 3rd param in the SUBSTR
     <varchar> Digits # Using the above example this would be the `01168779` position.
);
```

The problem is that these queries also must run in sequential order (currently using a PHP script to call them which is working perfectly, but each query is taking some time to complete. No real way I can see to speed this up but I welcome optimizations if possible.

Comment: Have you tried making the conversion?

Comment: not a lot of documentation regarding doing updates to a table by passing the table name and inline calculations .  also some normal query commands don't work and i know there are some tricks to it, so ya...   sorry for the vague summary of my attempts but too many attempts, all no closer to completion than the above and posting them would just add to the confusion probably leading to an incorrect solution.  i feel the above details enough about the problem to get a specific solution to this specific question :)

Comment: are you saying you have a table named '2015-06'?

Comment: @danb - yes.  actually, the tables are in the format going back for about 15 years.

Comment: So you want to write a stored procedure to do all the updates to improve efficiency?  Do you think that would reduce calls to the server.  Not sure what you are looking to do.

Comment: @danb I am thinking if this was written as a stored proc, it would improve the efficiency.  As stated above, any suggestions for improvements would be welcome keeping in mind the numbers that change. So far, the most efficient and accurate way I have found to do this is as above,  starting with the largest digit groups first, and going in sequence so their can be no mistake in the stored calculation.  My only issue now is speed. Whole process takes about 45 minutes to run the above for 4270 variations (0.63 seconds per query).

Comment: @SanuelJackson What makes you think a stored procedure would improve efficiency?

Comment: How does the number of updates compare to the number of rows in the table?  If it is small  then which parameter filters out more, cost or dialed?  Do you have an index on cost?  You may want to try using `Dialed` like '01168779%' and making sure there is an index on 'Dialed' if that filters out a significant number of rows.  Or you could try an index on cost and dialed in combination with 'like'

Comment: @danb - The number of rows is only about 100,000, so it really shouldn't take this long imho.

Comment: @SanuelJackson  True it should not. What about my other questions regarding indexes and how the percentage of rows that are updated.  Is it 100000 per month?

Comment: @danb - yes, it is 100k / month.  The search column `Dialed` is indexed so is `id` of course. The select portion runs fairly quick, it is the Update which is taking a while.

Comment: The only index that helps for the statement as is would be `cost`.   You have to change to using `like '01168779%` to use the index on `Dialed`

Comment: @danb - The problem with using Like, is it excludes exact matches. So for example, Like 'foo%', would return 'foobar', but not just 'foo'... at least when I original wrote the query. I started using like % for the digit group, but had to change to the more complex SUBTSR(1,count) to accomodate for exact scenarios. It just seems to me that on such a small recordset, this should not really be that slow.  mysqlslow doesn't return anything except that the query is taking more time.

Comment: No not true. % matches 0 characters. Do you have an index on Cost?  As an aside it would be helpful if you answer all my questions in the comment so I don't have to keep asking.  You have not answered whether there is an index on Cost yet.   Also have you tried to run an individual query?  I dont think a stored procedure will help. Something else is going on.